# Adding another context to a spring application

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

How can I add to web xml another context?

This is my PersistanceContext written as a java class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "ro.academy.model.daos"
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ro.academy.service")
public class PersistenceContext {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
        BasicDataSource dataSourceConfig = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSourceConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.petrikainulainen.springdata.jpa.todo");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
        //that is optimized for the used database.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
        //SessionFactory is created or closed.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")
        );

        //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
        //new database objects and schema elements
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy")
        );

        //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
        //statements to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql")
        );

        //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
        //that is written to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql")
        );

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Web xml which has another application context (I think it's the default one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the current application context written as a xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

It seems that spring does not recognize my PersistanceContext where I have all my configuration.

How can I add it to the application or make spring recognize it? 
Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")`as another annotation on the PersistentContext Class.

Also add `<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>` in web.xml

Alternately if you want take  reverse approach,

You need to add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.javaconfig" />` package in spring context xml file to load java config from spring xml

Change base-package to the package name where java config is residing.